# Insert geometry LINE value using PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to insert line value into table.
I already inserted point by using the folowing command:

```
INSERT INTO public."Sample"(point)
    VALUES ( point(-71.060316, 48.432044));
```

but the similar command for line insertion:

```
INSERT INTO public."Sample"(line)
    VALUES ( line( { -71.1, 48.2, 1.3}));
```

doesn't work.
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These native types do not have operator-constructors. They're implicitly coerced from strings.. Native types means that the database has native methods of storing and indexing them, not methods available to you to construct them from sql.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT
  linestr::line AS doublecolon,    // different ways to cast.
  line(linestr) AS functionconst,  // different ways to cast.
  CAST(linestr AS line) AS cast    // different ways to cast.
FROM (
  VALUES ( '{-71.1,48.2,1.3}'::text )
) AS t(linestr);
```

To construct a line..